# On iOS 8, using swift, UIAlertView is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

`UIAlertView` is taking over 30 seconds to display the alert in iOS 7 and 8.

Here's how I'm using it:

```
var alert = UIAlertView(
 title: "There was a problem Changing your password.",  
 message: errorMessage, 
 delegate: nil, 
 cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
alert.show()
```

I'm calling this in a `UIViewController` subclass that is showing.  I've tried using this, with the same effect:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "There was a problem Changing your password.", message: errorMessage, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
})
```

Also, it's just as slow in iOS 7 as in 8.

Comment: Of course it's going to take a while to display it. You are using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in` which slows down your stuff.

Comment: why are you doing that ?

Comment: I don't think the issue is with your alert code. The issue is probably elsewhere - you're doing something that's taking about 30 seconds, and the work is blocking the main thread. (Probably downloading stuff). Do you have any networking or other long-running work that gets called right before this alert view code?

Comment: Please can you show more code around this call. Nothing here should take 30 seconds to display the alert. What else is your app doing at the same time? Are you making a network request or something?

Comment: I don't think that your issue is in lines you have posted. just add `println(NSDate())` before and after `alert.show()` line. Then check if it really takes so long to show alert. you can also visually check time between when log and alert appearing

Comment: Verify if before this code you have somethings that execute in main thread or not.

Comment: I'm using it with a network notification.  The network call is speedy, I timed it in the log, less than 1 second.  It seems to have to do with NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName.  If I show the alert in addObserverForName, it will wait a long time.  If I show the alert in the networking class, it will also take a long time, unless I use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue().  If I do that, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not solve the problem you're having specifically, but in iOS 8 `UIAlertView` is deprecated in favour of `UIAlertController`. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController)